# Android drawables and style: No resource found that matches name in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, attr

When compiling my app, the following errors show up :

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:frameDuration'.
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:selectionDividerHeight'.   
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowLarge'.      
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:foregroundInsidePadding'.
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:listItemLayout'.
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel'.
```

As I'm new to this, it's not obvious to me.
I tried adding `@android:style/`, even removing the `@`, without changes to the result.

Here is `styles.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Ab" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_ab</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:selectionDividerHeight">@drawable/selectable_background_ab</item>
    <item name="android:frameDuration">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="OverflowStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowLarge">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_background</item>
    <item name="android:listItemLayout">@drawable/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:foregroundInsidePadding">@drawable/border_top_tabbar</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="DropDownListView.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Ab" parent="@android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="DropDownNav.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_ab</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_ab</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="ProgressBar.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Ab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_ab</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Ab.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Ab</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Ab</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Can you please help me solving this.

Comment: Why would you be setting frameDuration or dividerHeight to be drawables?

Comment: The correct syntax is `@android:style/`. Try to be consistent in that

Comment: well that isn't my code, I don't know, I'm trying to update an app developped by the former employee

Comment: @cricket_007 okay, edited all instances of `style` and `android:style` to `@android:style/`

Comment: There is a significant difference between `@style` and `@android:style`. For example, `@android:style/style/ActionBar.Solid.Ab`. This is not correct, for 1) you've doubled the "/style/" reference 2) You have defined that yourself. It is not part of the Android SDK styles.

Comment: Your previous edition was more correct. Just the `parent` attributes were mostly wrong. For example, you had `parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`, but that isn't related to your error necessarily. Since we cannot see how you are applying these themes in the rest of the code, what trouble would be caused by removing those troublesome elements?

Comment: thanks for the sharp eyes and the interesting lesson ! really appreciated

Comment: Basically, anything with `.Ab` in the name or `OverflowStyle` only uses `@style`. Anything that you can find otherwise in android's [`R.attr`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) or [`R.style`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html), you prefix with `android:`

Comment: @cricket_007 the `parent` attributes call for xmls from the SDK : `parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` looks for `themes_holo.xml` from Android-25 SDK

Comment: @cricket_007 found out my project was the missing the `R.java` containing my drawables, but how do I add it so that it is linked again to the drawables from my styles.xml ?

Comment: The `R.java` file is auto-generated when your app can compile and be built successfully. Your errors are preventing that.

Comment: mmmh...the only other place where I find these is in `public.xml` in my `res/values` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:frameDuration'.
> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:selectionDividerHeight'.
> ```

Both those values should be integers, not drawables. Besides that, I'm not sure it makes sense to apply those values onto a Theme. The duration would be applied to a `ProgressBar` and the `selectionDividerHeight` to some variant of a an `AdapterView` such an `ListView` / `GridView`.

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowLarge'.

Not sure about that... That theme definitely exists. Make sure you use `@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadgeSmall.WindowLarge`

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L784

> ```
> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:foregroundInsidePadding'.
> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:listItemLayout'.
> ```

The only reference I can find for the insidePadding says its value is true/false, not a drawable.
I'm not sure about the `listItemLayout`, but there [is a similar attribute only used by the IDE](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolslistitem_toolslistheader_toolslistfooter). An adapter is what is responsible for actually inflating the proper layout.

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel'

Again, this one also exists.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L137

Comment: thank you ! figured it out, the attribute name for the drawable was simply not the right one(I do not know how that happened though), same for the resources from the framework. It's all thanks to you. You really manage to make me curious and interested